# Recognize a place in Istanbul from an old (1890-1900) postcard

Tags: turkey, identify-this, istanbul

This postcard shows allegedly some place in Istanbul (Constantinople) in 1890-1900.
Could you help me to find its location on a map?

[image]

Comment: Just to ask some obvious questions - are you SURE it's Istanbul, and where did you get the postcard from? (Just in case it helps the search)

Comment: I've got it from Greece, the grandfather of one seller on Etsy was allegedly living there in late 1890s.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with Istanbul but this appears to be a navy building:

[Old photo here](https://www.pinterest.com.au/pin/344806915213961892/) from a similar angle.

[Location on Google maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Kuzey+Deniz+Saha+Komutanligi/@41.0313073,28.9650662,379m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x14cab9e042df9b4d:0xafe799ae786ca355!2zRXZsaXlhIMOHZWxlYmksIE1lxZ9ydXRpeWV0IENkLiwgQmV5b8SfbHUvxLBzdGFuYnVsLCBUdXJrZXk!3b1!8m2!3d41.0306907!4d28.9735597!3m4!1s0x14cab9e34f290847:0xcb208039https://www.google.com/maps/place/Kuzey+Deniz+Saha+Komutanligi/@41.0313073,28.9650662,379m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x14cab9e042df9b4d:0xafe799ae786ca355!2zRXZsaXlhIMOHZWxlYmksIE1lxZ9ydXRpeWV0IENkLiwgQmV5b8SfbHUvxLBzdGFuYnVsLCBUdXJrZXk!3b1!8m2!3d41.0306907!4d28.9735597!3m4!1s0x14cab9e34f290847:0xcb208039)

[Photo pre-renovation](http://wowturkey.com/t.php?p=/tr464/Erol_Gunduz_KuzeyDenizSahaKomutanligi_69.jpg)

Modern view:
[image]